# Write if else loop in simple way to reduce time complexity

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, if-statement

I have the below code

```
for i in range(index, len(df_2)+1):
  if df_2.loc[i, 'Duration'] == 0:
       df_2.loc[i, 'Duration'] = df_2.loc[i, "idle_hrs"] + df_2.loc[i - 1, "Duration"]
```

How can i write this in simple way to reduce time complexity? is there a war to write it in list comprehension style?

Comment: please provide a minimal example for verification. What is the output for duration = [0 1 0 0 3 ] and idle_hrs = [3 2 3 1 3]?

Comment: It should be possible to vectorize that by using a `shift`. But I shall not try to answer without a **copyable** example input data and the expected output...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift` for the accumulation.

```
import pandas as pd

index = 2
df = pd.DataFrame({'Duration': [1,0,2,0], 'idle_hrs': [10,20,30,40]})

df
Duration  idle_hrs
0         1        10
1         0        20
2         2        30
3         0        40

start_df = df[:index]
df.loc[df['Duration'] == 0, 'Duration'] = df['idle_hrs'] + df['Duration'].shift(1)
df.iloc[:index] = start_df

df
Duration  idle_hrs
0       1.0        10
1       0.0        20
2       2.0        30
3      42.0        40
```